# How to get push notification in PHP from attendance machine

Tags: php

```
$zk = new ZKLibrary('192.168.0.250', 4370);
$zk->connect();
$zk->disableDevice();
$users = $zk->getAttendance();
```

Here we get the all the data from the attendance machine by using this code. But we want to use push notification so that any one punch the machine, at the same time we get the attendance on our server.

Comment: What have you tried? Got any code?

Comment: No, I didn't get any code.

Comment: I feel like there is a lot of data needed to answer this question - What the data coming back looks like, what ZKLibrary does exactly, your push notification platform, etc...

Comment: Actually i am not able to get the data which is exactly coming from the machine. If we know the format of the data which machine is sending to URL, then we are able to do that. A

Comment: How to detect the format of the data send by the machine in PHP.

Comment: When you get some you will be able to look at it and decide what format it is

Comment: In your code you are using the ZKLibrary, but in the explanation you use the word Push.

Are you talking about PushSDK?

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution is to set **Task Scheduler (Windows) / Cronjob (Linux)** to do the checking every minute or every 5 minutes by executing your PHP code.

Here is the step for Windows OS:

1. **Create a batch file**. Put your code with PHP execution.

Example;

*Filename: attendance.bat*

```
php C:\wamp64\www\example2\zkteco\getAttendance.php
```

> If you get error -> "php is not recognized as an internal or external command " then watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka44kcFSruk

2. **Set your Task Scheduler** to run the attendance.bat
   Go to SEARCH at your **windows start**, then search for **Task** and **Click Task Scheduler.**

Remaining steps follow this youtube link -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Joxkb9y_UA

Comment: I purposely put the youtube link because its easier to follow.